# Swift SpriteKit touchesBegan detect right/left

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

So in my application I am using the code below to bounce the ball, but the problem is that the ball bounces left if I press right, and left if I press left. If I press in the middle it bouncec straight up as normal. This is the code I am using:

```
var PlayingFlag:Bool = false
let jumpAmount:Double = 310.0
var Ballx1:CGFloat = 0.0
var Ballx2:CGFloat = 0.0
var Ballx3:CGFloat = 0.0
var Ballx4:CGFloat = 0.0
var BallMoveAmount = (10.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0)

func CreateBall(){

        let ballTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
        ballTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest
        self.ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture)
        self.ball!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: ballTexture, size: ball!.size)
        self.ball!.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.ball!.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        self.ball!.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.6
        self.ball!.physicsBody?.mass = 0.430 // m = 430g
        self.ball!.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2 , y: self.frame.size.height)
        self.ball!.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x1 << 1
        self.ball!.zPosition = 10
        self.addChild(self.ball!)

        let Ballx0 = ball!.size.width
        self.Ballx1 = Ballx0 * 0.2
        self.Ballx2 = Ballx0 * 0.4
        self.Ballx3 = Ballx0 * 0.6
        self.Ballx4 = Ballx0 * 0.8
    }

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let ballHeight = self.ball!.size.height
            for touch : UITouch in touches{

                let tpoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
                if tpoint.y < (self.ball!.position.y + (ballHeight / 2.0)) {
                    if tpoint.y > (self.ball!.position.y - (ballHeight / 2.0))
                    {
                        var xpower:Double = 0.0
                        let xpo = abs(tpoint.x - self.ball!.position.x)
                        if(xpo < self.Ballx1){
                            xpower = BallMoveAmount.0
                        }else if (xpo < self.Ballx2) {
                            xpower = BallMoveAmount.1
                        }else if (xpo < self.Ballx3) {
                            xpower = BallMoveAmount.2
                        }else if (xpo < self.Ballx4) {
                            xpower = BallMoveAmount.3
                        }else{
                            return
                        }

                        if xpo > 0 {
                            xpower = xpower * -1
                        }
                        self.ball!.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero
                        self.ball!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: xpower, dy: self.jumpAmount))
                        self.ball!.runAction(se_ball)

                        if !self.PlayingFlag { // initial touch
                            self.gonode?.removeFromParent()
                            self.PlayingFlag = true
                        }else{
                            //something else
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if !self.PlayingFlag { return }
        if contact.bodyA.node == self.floorSprite || contact.bodyB.node == self.floorSprite {

            self.PlayingFlag = false

            // Game over...

            self.ball?.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this function:

```
func vectorFrom(point pointA: CGPoint, to pointB: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        let vector = CGVector(dx: pointB.x - pointA.x, dy: 310.0)
        return vector
    }
```

And then change this line:

```
self.ball!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: xpower, dy: self.jumpAmount))
```

to this:

```
let dirVector = vectorFrom(point: tpoint, to: ball!.position)
ball!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(dirVector)
```

Let me know if this didn't work out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if xpo > 0 {
    xpower = xpower * -1
}
```

To

```
if xpo > 0 {
    xpower = xpower * 1.5
}
```

Comment: Yes you place this logic in your method when the right button is pressed. And likewise for the former would go in your method that is called when the left button is pressed.